# How to reset vue product filter?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to reset my product filter.
Filter work by same code

```
 filteredData: function () {
      var vm = this
      var sf = vm.startFloor;
      var ef = vm.endFloor;
      var sa = vm.startSquare;
      var ea = vm.endSquare;
      var sp = vm.startPrice;
      var ep = vm.endPrice;
      return _.filter(this.avalFloors, (function (data) {
        if ((_.isNull(sf) && _.isNull(ef)) && (_.isNull(sa) && _.isNull(ea)) && (_.isNull(sp) && _.isNull(ep))) {
          return true
        } else {
          var areaf = data.areaf;
          var floor = data.floorf;
          var pricef = data.pricef;
          return (floor >= sf && floor <= ef) && (areaf >= sa && areaf <= ea) && (pricef >= sp && pricef <= ep);
        }
      }))
    }
```

How I can reset this by @click button?

Comment: It's unknown how this filter is used. Generally you need to reset data the filter depends on (startFloor, etc) to initial values

Comment: @click will call a function.  that function should reset values to initial.  if you need help, explain what the trouble is.